# Django how can i use variable in get query?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class accounts(models.Model):
    twitterid = models.IntegerField()
    credit    = models.IntegerField()
    activate  = models.TextField()
    group     = models.TextField()
    ban       = models.TextField(blank=True)
    others    = models.TextField()
class group(models.Model):
    groupname        =  models.TextField()
    groupfollowers   = models.IntegerField()


userid = request.session['userid']
juser = accounts.objects.get(twitterid=int(userid))
jgrp = group.objects.get(groupname=juser.group)
```

If I use jgrp = group.objects.get(groupname="beginners") this code is working but don't accept variable? 
DoesNotExist: group matching query does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure juser.group is a string name and not an object itself?  Your syntax appears to be correct but I'm guessing you are using juser.group incorrectly.

Comment: What does it mean it "doesn't accept variable"? What error do you get? My guess would be that `juser.group` is not a string, but it's hard to tell without details about your error.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting. You models are a little strange, (You could be using foreign keys, etc.) but everything seems fine. We need to see the error. it might be that `accounts.group` needs to be a `CharField` instead of a `TextField`. I don't know.

Comment: I edit questions and share my model now you can relook.

Comment: `juser.group` is empty and your `account` isn't connected to the `group` model so you would get errors if you think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

jgrp = group.objects.get(groupname=juser.group)

This code is perfectly valid. problem is, there is no corresponding group object for your account.group value.

I also think that your data model is not really ideal for a relational db. I think you should have a foreign key from your account model to group model so you can just use juser.group as @knapo suggested.

Answer (score 0):

`group` is an object and you need the name of the group. So probally `=juser.group.name`

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to replace the last line with this:

```
jgrp = juser.group
```